# Flake8 throws B008 fastapi data type definitions

Tags: python, fastapi, typing, flake8

I have the following code, which processes a `POST` request via `fastapi`. However, `flake8` keeps throwing the `B008 Do not perform function calls in argument defaults.  The call is performed only once at function definition time` error.

```
@app.post("/predict", status_code=200)
def predict(
    page_no: int = Form(...), dimensions: list = Form(...), image: UploadFile = File(...)
) -> Dict[str, int]:
```

Is there a way to fix these warnings, or work around them?

Comment: Do you want to silence them (add them to your `ignore=` list in `~/.flake8`), or stop using a function call as an argument default?

Comment: That would depend on what you want to achieve, generally you can use different rules for ignoring certain errors. Have you seen https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/5.0.4/user/violations.html ? It's also worth nothing that these errors are from flake8-bugbear, not plain flake8 or pycodestyles

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to to update your flake8 configuration (e.g. in your `setup.cfg` file) to ignore this rule for the `Depends(...)` usage like this:

```
extend-immutable-calls = Depends, fastapi.Depends, fastapi.params.Depends
```

As of Dec 2022, you have to list the names manually, as the flake8-bugbear plugin doesn't know about the actual types (it's an AST parser), [there is an open issue about it](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8-bugbear/issues/252).

**See more:**

- https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1522
- https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8-bugbear/issues/252